# QML Alias of tab components

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to make alias of a component contained inside a tab element but without success. Even this small example does not work :

```
Tab 
{
    id: tab1
    title:'tab1'

    property alias tab1Text: test.text

    Text {
        id:test
        text:'Test123'
    }    
}
```

I got this error :

```
property alias tab1Text: test.text
```

Can somebody indicate me where is the issue and how can I fix it ?

Comment: Your wording is correct: It is a **component** inside a Tab element. **Components** are not the real instance, they are something like a prototype/factory for instances. Since there is no real instance, you can't specify something inside a component to be the target of an alias.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand. (1) I have to enclose my tab data inside an Item to get aliases. (2) I must force loading of tab using active=true. Is it correct ? (from a single test it seems to work but I want to have the correct/best/prefered way to do it.

Comment: No, the enclosing inside an `Item` is useless. I mean - it will create an alias, but only inside the loaded object. It won't help you to get the data to the outside. Using `active:true` is enough  to access the text via `tab1.item.text`. If you create a property (that can only be used to read from the `test`-text) in the `Tab` write `property string tab1Text: (item ? item.text : '')` - this will load the text, once the `Text {..}` is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

You can't alias to a direct child of the [`Tab`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tab.html) since its content is not loaded by default:

> A Tab item inherits from Loader and provides a similar API.
>
> Tabs are lazily loaded; only tabs that have been made current (for
>   example, by clicking on them) will have valid content.

What you can do is using a property on [`item`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#item-prop) instead of an alias:

```
Tab {
    id: tab1
    title: 'tab1'
    active: true
    property string tab1Text: tab1.item ? tab1.item.text : ""

    Text {
        id: test
        text: 'Test123'
    }
}
```

But still it will be bound to the actual text only if the content is loaded (current Tab or with `active: true`).

You can also add an `Item` around your content:

```
Tab {
    id: tab1
    title: 'tab1'

    Item {
        property alias tab1Text: test.text

        Text {
            id: test
            text: 'Test123'
        }
    }
}
```

But still the alias will not be available outside of this Item (including at the root of the tab).

Comment: "since its content is not loaded by default:". I understand that so I force loading using active:true but it does not allow me to provide alias. The first solution is not ok for me because I want to pass a model to the root (the example is trivial but the real app is a tab that contains multiple comboboxes)

Comment: You can use a property on `tab1.item.text` instead of an alias

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs since the target of your alias declaration is not valid.

In QML you need to distinguish between **Object** and **Component** and what you have is not always transparent to the user.

Sometimes you can find in the documentation a property like [sourceComponent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#sourceComponent-prop)

```
sourceComponent: Component
```

If you assign something to it, like:

```
sourceComponent: Item {}
```

the `Item` won't be instantiated. Instead a `Component` for this `Item` is *implicitly* created that can then be used to create `Item`s. But since there is no instance of the `Item` yet, you also can't access any properties inside this non-existent `Item`.

Then in QML you have something called `default property`.
This property is the place to which all the subobjects are automatically assigned to.

```
Tab {
    Item {}
}
```

and

```
Tab {
    sourceComponent: Item {}
}
```

are equivalent. In most cases the default property is not of type `Component`, so the assigned thing is directly instantiated.

---

Now how to solve the problem? You might set `active: true` and read or write to `theTab.item.theProperty` using bindings, but you still can't alias to it since the syntax for alias only allows `id.property` and not `id.someProperty.someNestedProperty`.

But setting `active: true` implies that not only the properties are created, but all visual items, which is usually not desired. In my opinion, the best way is, to keep data and visual representation separated from each other:
You can have a *ViewModel* in which you have all the data stored, and you use the visual representation to bind to it. So the binding is initiated by the `Tab` to read (and possibly modify) the `text`. And your other object does the same, to the same property of the model object.

*A model is not necessarily some sort of list of objects. It might be just one object with various properties for your view to display.*

Comment: very useful comprehensive walk though, appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a string property in `Tab` and bind `Text.text` to it. Binding is created when Tab's dynamic content is loaded. No need to force loading of tabs with `active` property.

```
TabView {
    id: tabView

    function setTab2Text(txt) {
        tab2.tab2Text = txt
    }

    Tab
    {
        id: tab1
        title:'tab1'
        property string tab1Text: 'Test123'
        Text {
            id:test
            text: tab1.tab1Text
        }
    }
    Tab
    {
        id: tab2
        title:'tab2'
        property string tab2Text
        Text {
            id:test2
            text: tab2.tab2Text
        }
    }
    Component.onCompleted: setTab2Text('Test456')
}
```

Comment: The problem is, that if the `Text.text` text is changed from within the component, this binding wont work, an `alias` however would.

Comment: It's not possible to use alias with Quick Controls 1 Tab which is based on Loader. One possibility is to switch to Quick Controls 2 and use [TabButton](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-tabbutton.html) and [TabBar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-navigation.html#tabbar)

Comment: I know that it is not possible. But the property binding of yours is not equivalent. You should point that out.