# QML scope: Invalid alias reference

Tags: qt, qml

I get the following error: `qrc:/main.qml:17 Invalid alias reference. Unable to find id "button2"`. The error can be reproduced by the following qml file:

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Item {
    id: root

    property alias myprop: button2


    SplitView {
        id: splitView
        orientation: Qt.Vertical

        SplitView {
            id: splitView1
            orientation: Qt.Horizontal
            TabView {
                Tab{
                    title: "Tab1"
                }
                Tab{
                    title: "Tab2"

                    ColumnLayout {
                        GridLayout {
                            Button {
                                id: button2
                                text: qsTr("test button")
                            }
                        }


                    }
                }
            }


        }
    }
    }
}
```

It seems I have a misunderstanding about qml scope. I thought the parent can access the ids of all of its children?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QML Alias of tab components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49728888/qml-alias-of-tab-components)

Comment: You are most likely right, I will check

Comment: Yes, if I use a TabBar it is working, so it seems indeed to be the tabview